# Is it possible to load data from app's local database in app extension?

Tags: ios, swift, ios-app-extension

**Is it possible to load data from app's local database in app extension?**

I have one requirement to use app's local database in app extension.

Is it possible? if yes then give some sources.

Comment: Have a look at this document: https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/General/Conceptual/ExtensibilityPG/ExtensionScenarios.html

Answer (score 0):

The only way you can share data between the main app and the extension is through userDefaults with suiteName by using app groups , so if you can write all your data from database to defaults then it'll be shared , but the problem is that it's not a recommended way as always defaults holds configuration data , also extension must be launched first so app can read data from it

Comment: is it possible to call webservice in extension?

Answer (score 0):

You have to use Application group identifier, the you can share data with the `NSUserDefaults`. https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/General/Conceptual/ExtensibilityPG/ExtensionScenarios.html

You can use the same Application group identifier to acces a shared directory:

```
NSURL *groupURL = [[NSFileManager defaultManager]
    containerURLForSecurityApplicationGroupIdentifier:
        @"com.yourapp.domain"];
```

Extension can use the network to fetch data.

Comment: That means i can use container app's resource file (.txt or .json) in app extension?

Comment: Yes, this blog explains it in detail: http://www.atomicbird.com/blog/sharing-with-app-extensions

Comment: Ohhk. Thank u so much for sharing.

Comment: Do you have any demo?

Answer (score 0):

You can share everything between a host app and its app extensions:

- Keychain via keychain sharing
- UserDefaults via app groups
- Files via app groups
- Database via SQLite file and app groups

To share a database between host app and extension you simply put the database file into the shared storage of the app group. This way, any change in the database of the host app is instantly available in the database of the extension and vice versa. With the [CoreStore](https://github.com/JohnEstropia/CoreStore) framework it is very easy to set up a database in the app group storage:

```
import CoreStore

let dataStack: DataStack = {
    let dataStack = DataStack(xcodeModelName: "App")
    let storagePathUrl = FileManager.default.containerURL(forSecurityApplicationGroupIdentifier: "group.com.company.App")!.appendingPathComponent("App.sqlite")
    do {
        try dataStack.addStorageAndWait(SQLiteStore(fileURL: storagePathUrl, configuration: "Default", localStorageOptions: .
            recreateStoreOnModelMismatch))
    } catch let error {
        print("Cannot set up database storage: \(error)")
    }
    return dataStack
}()
```

An example to insert a user object (User must be definded in your App.xcdatamodeld) into the database would then be:

```
dataStack.perform(asynchronous: { transaction in
    let user = transaction.create(Into<User>())
    user.email = "user@test.com"
    user.name = "test"
}, completion: { _ in })
```

Please note that you must handle locking by yourself if host app and extension run at the same time and write to the database at the same time.